# regular expression get a string between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string :

```
# userid name uniqueid connected ping loss state rate
# 529 2 "arioch83" STEAM_1:0:86796179 55:58 99 0 active 80000
# 619 3 "Snake" STEAM_1:0:27678629 06:42 61 0 active 80000
# 622 4 "Captain_Selleri" STEAM_1:1:47927314 03:25 44 0 active 80000
# 583 5 "krN[786]" STEAM_1:1:14638235 28:53 53 0 active 128000
# 621 6 "Giack" STEAM_1:1:67468100 04:44 129 0 active 80000
# 326 7 "Urkrass" STEAM_1:0:55150382  3:02:31 51 0 active 80000
#613 "Vinny" BOT active
# 584 9 "Tkappa" STEAM_1:0:32266787 27:55 360 0 active 80000
# 605 10 "Narpok19" STEAM_1:0:44838130 14:36 67 0 active 80000
# 551 11 "robbetto83" STEAM_1:1:63675894 50:10 86 0 active 80000
# 530 12 "XxKazuyaxX" STEAM_1:0:18676379 55:57 68 0 active 80000
# 623 13 "beut3d - Keyser Söze" STEAM_1:0:14500718 00:29 70 0 active 80000
# 602 15 "Homroy" STEAM_1:1:7870901 16:34 169 0 active 80000
# 607 16 "[Bloody]Eagle" STEAM_1:1:59567346 09:14 77 0 active 80000
#615 "Jeff" BOT active
# 587 18 "Heisenberg" STEAM_1:1:61427218 25:15 81 0 active 80000
#end
```

And I want to get string between "# userid name uniqueid connected ping loss state rate" and "#end". I tryied several regex based on what I found on stackoverflow but none works :(
Here is my last attempt

```
var matches = text.match(/# userid name uniqueid connected ping loss state rate(.+)\&#end/);
                if (matches.length > 1) {
                    alert(matches[1]);
                }
```

As you can see I know nothing about regex... any good tuto about those ?

thanks,

Comment: For what your are looking for? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: [a toy](http://regex101.com/#javascript), [a guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), [a clue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be able to match across multiple lines. You are looking for the `s` (*dotall*) modifier. Unfortunately this modifier **does not** exist in JavaScript. A common workaround is replacing the dot `.` with the following:

```
[\S\s]
```

So you can use the following regular expression:

```
/# userid name uniqueid connected ping loss state rate([\S\s]*?)#end/
```

**Explanation**:

```
(               # group and capture to \1:
  [\S\s]*?      #   any character of: 
                #    non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), 
                #    whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") 
                #    (0 or more times matching the least amount possible)
)               # end of \1
```

[JavaScript Demo](https://eval.in/171970)

Comment: we can use `[\W\w]*` and `[\D\d]*` as well. Nice answer.

Comment: You should be able to use `[^]*` too.

Comment: There are many ways, yes, as I stated `A common workaround...`

Comment: @hwnd: if I put "groink#end" after the example string, your pattern will match it, you need to use a lazy quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using regular expressions, is to split the string by `\n` and extract the part that you want (everything from the second line to the second to last line):

```
var contents = "your contents here...";

var contentArray = contents.split( "\n" );

// extract the array elements from the second to the second from last and re-join with `\n`
console.log( contentArray.slice( 1, contentArray.length - 2 ).join( "\n" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the lines that is not started by `#userid` and `#end`

```
/^(?!#\s*(userid|end)).*/gmi
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/uU9jY6/22)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern that uses the fact that "#end" is at the start of a line:

```
/# userid name uniqueid connected ping loss state rate\n((?:.*\n)*?)#end/
```

But an other efficient way is to split the log into lines and to look at the start and end lines in the resulting list.